# How to properly assign assets to users based on their user roles, e.g. Admin, Manager, Viewer?

Tags: database, database-design

I have a database having `users` and `venues` tables for our customers.  The third table is `users managing venues`, with a many-to-many relationship.  `Admin` is always in charge of all the venues.  My question is, in the system should I put all the rows in `user managing venues` with `Admin` and each of venue.  Or I just handle this one on the application side and check if the user is the `Admin`, and if so, automatically fetch all the venues data from the database.  What would be the best practice?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend storing the rows explicitly in the table, for two reasons:

1. Storing the data in the table will protect you when the day comes (and it WILL come) that someone says "this user is an admin but only for this sub-set of venues".
2. I'm a data guy, not an application guy, so of COURSE I'm gonna say "store it in the data layer" :)

Comment: Hmm , thanks. Thats was good insight into future. Depending on that I am going to explicitly store in the record in table.

Comment: Glad I could help.  Let me know if you have other questions.  Don't forget to mark this as "accepted" - I'm given to understand it will help others find this discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should use this practice !
`put user managing venues with Admin and each of venue`.
on future requirement change or updating user status from manager to admin or any other, roles and access of each record will be easily due to each record is save with user access(admin,user).